# Why is the use of (>100) partial application?

Tags: haskell

This code illustrates the use of partial application through the use of an operator section :

```
gt100 :: Integer -> Bool
gt100 x = x > 100


greaterThan100 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
greaterThan100 xs = filter gt100 xs

greaterThan100_2 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
greaterThan100_2 xs = filter (\x -> x > 100) xs


greaterThan100_3 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
greaterThan100_3 xs = filter (>100) xs
```

The operator section (>100) partially applies the operator to one
of its two arguments. So the operator in this case is >
Why is this partial application as the > operator is being applied
to the entire Integer list ?

How is this different from lambda expression `(\x -> x > 100)` which
apparently is not partial application ?

Taken from http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/04-higher-order.html

Update :

Thanks to answers this appears clearer.

So here now is my understanding :

```
*Main> :t (>)
(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Is not applied at all as it accepts two parameters "a -> a" but they are not applied.

```
*Main> :t (>100)
(>100) :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

Is partially applied as a function of type "a -> Bool" is created

```
*Main> :t (3>100)
(3>100) :: Bool
```

Is evaluated to type Bool which is the return type of operator `(>)` as illustrated by `:t (>)`

Comment: In practice, it is not different, as they both have the same type and behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this partial application as the > operator is being applied to the entire Integer list ?

It is not applied to the entire list, as a whole, but to the individual elements, one by one. When the `>` is partially applied over 100, it creates a new function.

```
Prelude> :type (> 100)
(> 100) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

Now, the function accepts an argument and returns `Bool`. This function is applied to all the elements in the list by the `filter` function.

---

> How is this different from lambda expression (\x -> x > 100) which apparently is not partial application ?

`>` is a function which needs two operands to operate. You are already passing one of them, as `100`. To completely execute the function, you need one more argument. So, the function `>` is partially applied with `100`.

In the second case, you are creating a new function which needs only one argument to execute. Once you pass that argument, your function will be executed. So, the lambda function is not applied partially.

Answer (score 4):

> How is this [`(<) 100`] different from lambda expression `(\x -> (<) 100 x)` which apparently is not partial application? [1]

I think it is important to draw a distinction between semantic properties and syntactic properties. The two terms you suggested are *semantically* identical -- that is, there is no Haskell function you can write that reduces to one thing when applied to `(<) 100` and reduces to a different thing when applied to `(\x -> (<) 100 x)`.

However, partial application is a *syntactic* property -- that is, it is a property not of the *behavior* of a term but of the *particular implementation* chosen. (In analogous terms to my definition of a semantic property, a syntactic property is about whether you could write a Haskell function that reduces to one thing when applied to *the string* `"(<) 100"` and reduces to a different thing when applied to the string `"(\x -> (<) 100 x)"`, which is eminently possible.) If I had to define it, I would define it this way: partial application is an application term with an arrow type. [2] Both of your terms are well-typed and have arrow types. But `(<) 100` is an application term, whereas `\x -> (<) 100 x` is a lambda term (that has an application in its body).

As for operator sections like `(100<)` and `(>100)`, it is not immediately obvious what to do with these. One choice is to simply decree that all operator sections are partial applications (or to simply decree that no operator sections are partial applications, of course). Another is to treat them as shorthand for `(<) 100` and `flip (>) 100`, respectively, in which case we would still consider them partial applications (since they are application terms and have arrow types). [3] Yet a third is to treat them as shorthand for `\x -> (<) 100 x` and `\x -> (>) x 100`, respectively, in which case one might claim they are not partial applications.

But the distinction is, in my opinion, not too important: generally, semantic properties are more interesting and useful than merely syntactic ones.

[1] To avoid muddying the waters, I have used `(<) 100` instead of `(>100)`. We will discuss this distinction shortly.
[2] There is some question about what to do if the type is polymorphic. Let's punt on that question for now.
[3] This differs from simply decreeing that all operator sections are partial applications; consider some one-argument operator `(!)` and its section `(100!)`, which we would then be treating as shorthand for `(!) 100`. This is an application term, but does not have an arrow in its type.